# Get to know when CacheNetworkImage successfully show network image

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using CacheNetworkImage for displaying an image, I have a use case like I have to show loading on the whole Container until the image is not rendered. Is there any way I can get to know that my image is successfully rendered on screen?

This is what I have done so far:

```
 return CachedNetworkImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      imageUrl: url,
      errorWidget: (a, b, c) => const Center(child: Icon(Icons.error_outline)),
      progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, _, DownloadProgress progress) {
        getProgressStatus(progress);
        return Shimmer(color: Colors.grey, child: const SizedBox.expand());
      },
    );
```

```
void getProgressStatus(DownloadProgress loadingStatus) {
    if (loadingStatus.downloaded == loadingStatus.totalSize) {
      scheduleMicrotask(() {
        setState(() {
          isLoaded = true;
        });
      });
      return;
    }

    scheduleMicrotask(() {
      setState(() {
       isLoaded = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can directly set your loader in progressIndicatorBuilder value. It will manage automatically.

Comment: How can I set it can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `placeholder` until the image is loaded. This is how you can use it.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                  placeholder: placeholderWidgetFn() as Widget Function(
                      BuildContext, String)?,
                  imageUrl: imgURL,
                  width: 300,
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2.5,
                ),
```

```
Widget? Function(BuildContext, String) placeholderWidgetFn() =>
    (_, s) => placeholderWidget();

Widget placeholderWidget() =>
    Image.asset('images/placeholder.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover);
```

Comment: Bro, It is showing only on Image Container but my use case is I want to place a placeholder on the whole Tile.

Answer (score 1):

**Usecase**: `I have a tile in which i have added CacheNetworkImage & I want to add the PlaceHolder on the whole tile until that specific image not loads.`

*See this image for what I want to achieve*

[image]

I have achieve this using Stack widget.

```
   Stack(
    children: [
      MyTile(
        image: CacheNetworkImage(imageUrl)
       ),
     SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: ///Same as your lower container
      child CacheNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.clear,
        placeholder: (context, _) {
             return MyPlaceHolder(...)
        },
      )
    ],
   ),
```

Note: `Image url for both the child's will be exactly same`

Answer (score 0):

By using progressIndicatorBuilder property of CachedNetworkImage you can manage it,

```
 progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
       Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.only(
               top: 100.h,
               bottom: 100.h
           ),
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(
               value: downloadProgress.progress,
               color: AppColors.lightBlack)),
           )
```

Comment: nope, It is not working

Comment: What's the result of above code?

Comment: It just show nothing no output

Comment: I want a PlaceHolder on my whole Tile not just on my Image